# JQuery: Click() to change list item font

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGXdf/)

Cant get this to work! I am hacking Jquery.tabs() functionality. Want the tab text to turn bold when selected. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
<div>
    <ul id="tablist">
        <li id ="li" aria-selected="true" >
            <a id="ui-id-1"  href="#tabs-Hobby">Hobby</a>
        </li>
        <li id="lw" aria-selected="false">
            <a id="ui-id-2" href="#tabs-News">News</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
  $(" ul li a").click(function()
   {
    if($("ul").find("li[aria-selected=true]")) {
    $("ul").find("li[aria-selected=true]").attr("style", "font-weight:bold")       
    }

    if($("ul").find("li[aria-selected=false]")) {
        $("ul").find("li[aria-selected=true]").attr("style", "font-weight:normal")       
    }
  });
```

Comment: Any reason you're altering the style of the elements themselves, and not just making this a couple of styles in your style sheet?

Comment: [Do you want something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zGXdf/4/)?

Comment: fiddle and code posted  here are different

Answer (score 1):

All of the following notes are based on your jsFiddle.

1. Notice that this code runs only once on the start, so it will work only once:

   ```
   if($("li[aria-selected=true")) {
      $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
   }
   ```
2. Also, in the fiddle you gave us, there's nothing changing this attribute: `aria-selected`
3. Further more, you're missing a `]` on the selector in the `if` condition.
4. A better approach would be to not only change the `li`'s`aria-selected` on the button's click, but also give it a `CSS class`, called 'open' for example. Then, on your CSS, give all `li`s with this class `font-weight: bold`, and you're done.
5. You should start using [Data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) instead of [Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/category/Attributes/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("ul li a").click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'ui-id-1') {
            $('#ui-id-1').css("font-weight", "bold");
            $('#ui-id-2').css("font-weight", "normal");
        } else {
            $('#ui-id-1').css("font-weight", "normal");
            $('#ui-id-2').css("font-weight", "bold");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$(" ul#tablist li a").click(function()
{
 if($("ul#tablist").find("li[aria-selected=true]")) {
$("ul#tablist").find("li[aria-selected=true]").css("font-weight", "bold")       
}

if($("ul#tablist").find("li[aria-selected=false]")) {
    $("ul#tablist").find("li[aria-selected=true]").css("font-weight", "normal")       
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use `.css('font-weight', 'bold')` and `.css('font-weight', 'normal')` instead, respectively.